# C# Особенности метода String.Split()

Tags: c#, split

Можно ли как-либо сделать так, чтобы метод Split делил строку, когда встречает точку, но игнорировал, например "Mr."?
Пример: 
Строка: "Mr.Dark and Mrs.Dark went out for a walk. I got home late."
Надо получить: 
Строка 1: "Mr.Dark and Mrs.Dark went out for a walk" 
Строка 2: "I got home late"

Comment: Именно `Split` нужен? Это можно с помощью `Regex.Matches` сделать.

Comment: Если не сложно, можете хотя бы примерно объяснить как?

Comment: Буду дома, ответ напишу.

Comment: Просто основное задание состоит в том, чтобы очень большой текст поделить на предложения, а предложения на слова и записать это всё в список списков. И всё вроде неплохо, но в тексте есть 2 кривых момента: 1. Mr. и Mrs. 2. Строка "1.FIRST CHAPTER"

Comment: Помимо точки могут быть ? и ! знак?

Comment: Да, там могут быть: '!'  '?'  ';'  ':' '(' ')' Это всё разделители предложений

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957295/6808809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static List<string> Split(string text)
{
    string r = "~";
    return text.Replace("Mr.", $"Mr{r}")
        .Replace("Mrs.", $"Mrs{r}")
        .Split(new[] { ". ", "? ", "! " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(s => s.Replace($"Mr{r}", "Mr.")
        .Replace("Mrs" + r, "Mrs.")).ToList();
}
```

Смысл в том, что мы заменяем Mr. на (Mr~) затем используем метод Split() и меняем Mr~ обратно на Mr.

Используем:

```
string text = "Mr.Dark and Mrs.Dark went out for a walk. I got home late";

foreach (var i in Split(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Резутьтат:

```
Mr.Dark and Mrs.Dark went out for a walk
I got home late
```