# Разделить строку на массив слов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, split

Нужно разделить строку на массив слов, где в качестве разделителей, могут быть любые символы, кроме букв и символов `. ! ? ; : ( )`.
Догадываюсь, что тут не обойтись без регулярных выражений, но как их писать пока не знаю, а в интернете инфы по моему вопросу не нашел.

```
var wordsArray = sentences[i].Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Пишу на С#, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Приведите пример хотя бы. Буквы обычно не бывают разделителями.

Comment: Ну я же написал кроме букв и символов выше. ну например символы #$%, цифры 0-9, перечислять их думаю не самое правильное решение.

Comment: Попробуйте `Regex.Matches(s, @"[\p{L}.!?;:()]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value)`

Answer (score 4):

Вы ставите задачу как "разделители любые, а слово может состоять только из ограниченного набора символов" и эта задача решается намного сложнее, чем "слово может состоять из любых символов, а нужно описать разделители слов".

Давайте по-простому: разделитель слов -- это пробелы и знаки препинания. Всё.

У вас же будет сложнее: в слове могут встретиться дефисы (Иванов-Крамской), цифры (ТОП100), символы разных алфавитов, в том числе умлауты ("Männer") и прочая диакритика и многое, многое другое.

Вернитесь ещё раз к общему описанию своей задачи: "Нужно разделить строку на массив слов" и помедитируйте над тем, что проще описать: набор символов слова или набор символов-разделителей.

Плюс, буквально вчера пробегал такой же [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734253/213987) и там давали [ссылку на en-so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4957295/5752652) с регуляркой которая вам подойдёт в качестве основы. (Нужны будут например, кавычки ёлочкой)

```
string[] sentences = Regex.Split(input, @"(?<=[\.!\?])\s+");
```

Регулярки -- учите, это один из механизмов, который широко используется в разных языках и является тем, что нужно знать каждому программисту.

Но лично я бы пошёл по самому простому пути: регулярки не использовал, тут достаточно именно String.Split с параметром "массив разделителей". В основе регулярных выражений лежат конечные автоматы, это более сложный алгоритм, чем сплит -- и эта сложность здесь излишняя.

```
var sentence = "Роман «Война и мир» Л.Н. Толстого, написанный в 1869 году являлся...";
char[] separators = new char[] {' ', '.', ',', '!', '?', '»', '«'};
var wordsArray = sentence.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Вывод:

[image: выходные данные]